# iPhone Video and Data Capture

Tags: iphone, computer-vision, accelerometer, core-motion, data-collection

I am working on developing an iPhone app for automatic vision processing. In order to explore possible algorithms, I need to capture iphone video and sensor data at the same time. 
I have found many great apps for recording sensor data over a period of time, however, they stop recording when I switch to the iPhone video camera. If I start the video first and then switch to the data recording app, then the video stops. 
What I need is an app that can record data from any sensors (specifically I am looking for raw accelerometer, raw gyroscope, processed user acceleration, and processed attitude quaternion).  while simultaneously recording a video. Does anyone know if such an app exists or do I need to write one? 

thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Axis3D" purports to do this (record video, gyro and accelerometer data).